# PHP I have two arrays, I want to extract items from Array 1 if it's not already in Array 2

Tags: php, arrays

Like the title says, I have two arrays and I just want to get everything from the first array that's not already in the second array. How do I do this?

Comment: go to php.net/array read the list of functions and find what you need

Answer (score 6):

Use [`array_diff`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

```
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [1] => blue
)
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/Afsyw)

Comment: +1 for getting it some seconds first. Ah, that always happens. "2 new answers have been posted. Load them....sigh".

Answer (score 1):

```
$x=array(1,2,3,4);
$y=array(3,4);

$z=array_diff($x,$y);
var_dump($z);
```

This will output array(1,2)

Answer (score 0):

[array_diff() function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)